How to Add Clickable Links in Instagram Stories via API?
I am currently using the Instagram API to publish stories and I would like to know if it's possible to add clickable links directly within the stories via API.
Is there any official or unofficial way to achieve this programmatically through the Instagram API?
I appreciate any insights or examples that could point me in the right direction
Thank you very much !

Per the Story Limitations in the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-graph-api/reference/ig-user/media, it seems that it's not supported.
